# how caching data in mobile app to make it faster?

Tags: google-app-engine, caching, memcached, google-cloud-datastore

Im new in mobile app dev and i'm wondering if caching for the web and caching for the mobile native platform are the same thing.

I see popular apps like facebook twitter and spotify caching data in our mobile cache. What type of data do they store in our local memory  ?

What sould i use if a want to make a caching system for
 my app . Memcached powered by google app engine datastore that cache data in a cloud RAM  ?  Or should i rather cache data on the phone user  ?  What is the faster  ?  What is the most efficient  ? What type of data for a mobile app should be put in cache  ?

Thanks to bring me some light about this concern.

Comment: don't worry about caching until you have something to cache and speed is a problem.

Comment: @PaulCollingwood Thanks for your answer. Even if i don't have anything to catch i'm trying to understand the caching process. This is for my personal knowledges and i just think it's important to understand what type of data should be cached in the case of a mobile app and which way would be the best for caching (cloud or local cache)